# need to merge output of expand.grid into a cvs file in R

Tags: r, cvs

I have 20 different lists variable say

```
a= c("red" "blue"), b= c("circle", "square"), c= c("inside","outside")
```

I am taking the combinations between different list by the command:

```
 data1 <- expand.grid(a, b) 
 data2 <- expand.grid(a, d)
```

I want to merge all the output of `data1` , `data2`  into a single data set.

I would like to export the data into a cvs file.

Comment: It is not clear.  Please provide an example dataset and expected output.   Have you tried `merge`? What do you meant by `merge`

Comment: hmm just any dataset. for example a<- c("red", "blue)  and b<- ("triangle", "square", "circle").  then use data1 <- expand.grid(a,b). use a similar dimension for other data sets. using merge( data1, data2) then gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you example given, you could do this:

```
all_combined <- do.call("rbind",
  lapply(combn(list(a, b, c), 2, simplify = FALSE),
    do.call, what = "expand.grid")
)
```

Output

```
#     Var1    Var2
#1     red  circle
#2    blue  circle
#3     red  square
#4    blue  square
#5     red  inside
#6    blue  inside
#7     red outside
#8    blue outside
#9  circle  inside
#10 square  inside
#11 circle outside
#12 square outside
```

If you just wanted specific combinations, you could do:

```
data1 <- expand.grid(a, b)
data2 <- expand.grid(a, c)

combined <- rbind(data1, data2)
```

This could then be written to CSV using:

```
write.csv(combined, "CombinedData.csv")
```

Comment: Thnx! may i ask you how to store the output as a dataframe to export the file to excel?